# Permanently extending the behaviour of functions (like decorators)

Tags: programming, evaluation, design-patterns

Suppose I have a function, e.g.

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

It works like this:

```
f[5]
(* 25 *)
```

I would like to permanently modify it so that calling `f[5]` will perform some action before and after the evaluation of the original `f`.  For example, I would like `f` to *behave* like `ff` below:

```
ff[x_] := 
    Module[{res},
      Print["Before..."];
      res = f[x];
      Print["After..."];
      res
    ]

ff[5]

During evaluation of In[]:= Before...

During evaluation of In[]:= After...
(* 25 *)
```

I would like to do this without needing to know what `f` does, or how it behaves. Preferably, the modification should be carried out automatically.  This would be somewhat similar to decorators in Python.

The [Villegas–Gayley pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/695132) makes this feasible for built-in functions because built-in definitions always have lower priority than user-issued ones. But with user-defined functions this is much harder to do reliably because we cannot control the ordering of definitions.

---

Example application:

[Evaluate functions with a certain value of $ContextPath.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155564/12) Ideally, all the functions in the package described in the linked question could be modified in one line of code.

If we have

```
sym;
g[] := ToString[sym]
```

then

```
g[]
(* "sym" *)
```

Suppose we want to automatically modify `g[]` so that it behaves like

```
Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myEmpty`"}, g[]]
(* "Global`sym" *)
```

Comment: I am wondering if this is doable at all in a *robust* way without [copying the functions's definition over into another symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19902/12), and the modifying the original symbol to call the new function.  That seems a risky thing to do because the function may refer to itself (e.g.  if it's recursive).

Comment: If this is the last definition that will be set for `g` you can `PrependTo` `DownValues`, kind of, the funny thing is `g[]` pattern will stay on top but if you define `g[sym_]` it will work.

Comment: @Kuba That's one of the problems: Mathematica orders definitions automatically by generality, to some extent, so we can't insert our definition as the highest priority one.

Comment: Except `_[]` case the enforced order seems to be held. Quite often it will be good enough but it would be nice to have a more general solution.

Comment: The whole point of explicitly adjusting DownValues is to be able to control the order of definitions. The behavior for `_[]` seems like a bug.

Comment: @mmeent If you experiment a but, you'll see that adjusting `DownValues` is not different from issuing definitions. You can only reorder definitions which are considered of equal generality. `f[x_] := x^2; f[2] = 2; DownValues[f] = Reverse@DownValues[f]; f[2]`

Comment: Thing is that they are different. When issuing definitions `f[x_]:=...` is considered more general than `f[x_Real] :=...`, but you can reorder their definitions. So confusingly, MMA seems to be using different metrics for generality here.

Comment: @Szabolcs I was reminded of this question by a recent vote.  I note that you never Accepted an answer, and also that you did not comment on the method I proposed.  It still seems to me a simple and effective approach.  Does it fail you in some way?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do not recall why I did not accept one, and right now I cannot see anything wrong with your solution (but these things tend to be tricky...)

Comment: Well, thanks for the Accept. :-)  Most importantly I would like to know if and where my method fails, and if it is possible to craft a work-around in such cases.  Please let me know if you find either (failure, or workaround)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your requirements I would move the original symbol to a new context.

```
wrapper[fn_, mod_] :=
  Module[{ctxt = Context[fn], name = SymbolName[fn], x},
    Context[fn] = "wrapper`" <> ctxt <> ToString[x] <> "`";
    Symbol[ctxt <> name][arg___] := fn[arg] // Unevaluated // mod
  ]
```

Your example:

```
sym;
g[] := ToString[sym]

wrapper[g, Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myEmpty`"}, #] &]

g[]
```

> ```
> "Global`sym"
> ```

Recursion:

```
fib[1 | 2] = 1;
fib[n_Integer?Positive] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]

wrapper[fib, #2 &[Print["Before"], #, Print["After"]] &]

fib[7]
```

> Before
>
> After
>
> ```
> 13
> ```

Nested wrappers:

```
wrapper[fib, #2 &[Print["Primordial"], #, Print["Final"]] &]

fib[12]
```

> Primordial
>
> Before
>
> After
>
> Final
>
> ```
> 144
> ```

Related:

- [Same name for functions in package and Global context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103551/121)

Answer (score 16):

### Preamble

I've used similar constructs a number of times. This answer assumes that you want to decorate at definition time (which is what happens in python), rather than doing that after the definition has been created. If you need to add definitions to existing function, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2793/81) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106068/81) discussions can be helpful. If you have several definitions, you will need to decorate all of them (where you want the decorated behavior) separately.

### The main idea and simplest examples

#### The idea

Here is the idea:

```
ClearAll[decorator];
decorator /: SetDelayed[decorator[dec_][f_[args___]], rhs_]:=
  f[a:PatternSequence[args]]:=
     dec[Unevaluated @ f, Unevaluated @ {a}, Unevaluated @ rhs];
```

#### Links to similar usage examples

Here are a few links to answers where I previously used this method in one form or another - they can serve as additional examples of how this can be applied:

- [How to find the name of the current function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20620/81)
- [Generic templating system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80536/81)
- [Resource management in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1603/81) (the `lex` function there)
- [How to implement a discrete data representation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139871/81)
- [How to protect functions in a Mathematica Package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45784/81)

#### Tests

Here is how it can be used. First, we define our decorator

```
ClearAll[mydec];
mydec[f_, args_, rhs_] :=
  Module[{res},
    Print["Before..."];
    res = rhs;
    Print["After..."];
    res
  ]
```

Now, we define `f`:

```
decorator[mydec]@
 f[x_] := x^2;
```

We now test:

```
f[5]
```

> During evaluation of In[18]:= Before...
>
> During evaluation of In[18]:= After...

```
(* 25  *)
```

Here is your sample app:

```
decorator[
  Function[{f, args, rhs}, 
  Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myEmpty`"}, rhs]]
] @ g[] := ToString[sym]
```

then

```
g[]

(* Global`sym *)
```

### A more complete framework

#### The code

Here is the code for a more complete framework, which would, in particular, allow for decorator chaining:

```
ClearAll[decorator, customHold, foldRHS];
SetAttributes[{customHold, foldRHS}, HoldAll];

foldRHS[f_, args_, rhs_, decs_List]:=
  ReplaceRepeated[
    Hold @ Evaluate @ Fold[
      customHold[#2[f, args, #]]&, 
      customHold[Unevaluated[rhs]], 
      Reverse @ decs
    ],
    customHold[x___]:>x
  ]; 

decorator /: (h:(Set | SetDelayed))[decorator[decs__][decorator[d_][arg_]], rhs_]:=
  h[decorator[decs, d][arg], rhs];

decorator /: (h:(Set | SetDelayed))[
  decorator[decs__][f_[args___, o:Verbatim[OptionsPattern[]] | Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[OptionsPattern[]]]]],
  rhs_
]:=
  Module[{a, opts},
    h @@ Join[
      Hold[f[a:PatternSequence[args], opts: o]], 
      foldRHS[f, {a, opts}, rhs, {decs}]    
    ]
  ];    

decorator /: (h:(Set | SetDelayed))[decorator[decs__][f_[args___]], rhs_]:=
  Module[{a},
    h @@ Join[
      Hold[f[a:PatternSequence[args]]], 
      foldRHS[f, {a}, rhs, {decs}]  
    ]
  ];

decorator /: Set[decorator[decs__][lhs_], HoldPattern @ Function[args_, body_, attrs_:{}]]:=
  lhs = Function @@ Join[
    Hold[args],
    foldRHS[None, args, body, {decs}],
    Hold[attrs]
  ];
```

#### Simple examples

Let us define decorator generator, which can generate simple wrapping decorators:

```
ClearAll[dec];  
dec[name_, hold_:False]:=
  With[{atts = If[TrueQ @ hold, {HoldAll}, {}]},
    Function[{fun, args, rhs},
      Module[{res},
        Print["In ", name, " before..."];
        Print["Result of ", HoldForm[rhs], " : ", res = rhs];
        Print["In ", name, " after..."];
        res
      ],
      atts
    ]
  ];
```

And use them to define two functions:

```
ClearAll[f, ff];

decorator[dec["first"]] @
decorator[dec["second"]] @ 
f[x_]:=x^2

decorator[dec["first", True]] @
decorator[dec["second", True]] @ 
ff[x_]:=x^2
```

We can now test. In the first case, we see that the inner decorator executes before the outer one:

```
f[5]
```

> During evaluation of In[378]:= In second before...
>
> During evaluation of In[378]:= Result of 5^2 : 25
>
> During evaluation of In[378]:= In second after...
>
> During evaluation of In[378]:= In first before...
>
> During evaluation of In[378]:= Result of 25 : 25
>
> During evaluation of In[378]:= In first after...

```
(* 25 *)
```

because neither of them holds the internal code. But in the second case, the execution is happening from outside to inside:

```
ff[5]
```

> During evaluation of In[380]:= In first before...
>
> During evaluation of In[380]:= In second before...
>
> During evaluation of In[380]:= Result of 5^2 : 25
>
> During evaluation of In[380]:= In second after...
>
> ```
>   During evaluation of In[380]:= Result of 
>     Function[{fun$,args$,rhs$},Module[{res$},
>      Print[In ,second, before...];
>      Print[Result of ,rhs$, : ,res$=rhs$];
>      Print[In ,second, after...];res$],
>      {HoldAll}][ff,{5},Unevaluated[5^2]
>     ] : 25
> ```
>
> During evaluation of In[380]:= In first after...

```
(* 25 *)
```

#### Using pure functions

The `decorator` defined above also allows one to decorate definitions like this:

```
someVariable = Function[args, body]
```

So for example, the following `pf` function will behave like the `f` above:

```
decorator[dec["first"]] @
decorator[dec["second"]] @
pf = Function[x, x^2];
```

which can be easily checked.

#### An example: option validation

To add one less trivial example, I would like to show how option validation can be carried out using decorators. I will use [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116633/81) as a source of examples, although the validation process described below will be different (will check option values immediately as they are passed, unlike in my answer there, which was checking them once they were computed / used).

The following two functions will implement the option-checking logic:

```
ClearAll[checkOptions];
checkOptions[testF_][f_, args___, opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
  False =!= Replace[
    Flatten[{opts}], 
    (name_ -> val_) :>  If[!TrueQ @ testF[f, name, val], 
      Message[OptionCheck::invldopt, name, f, val];
      Return[False, Replace]    
    ],
    {1}
  ];

ClearAll[OptionCheck];
OptionCheck::invldopt = "Option `1` for function `2` received invalid value `3`";
OptionCheck[testFunction_]:=
  Function[
    {f, args, code},
    If[!checkOptions[testFunction][f, Sequence @@ args],
      Return[$Failed],
      (* else *)
      code
    ],
    HoldAll
  ];
```

Basically, `OptionCheck` takes a test function and generates a decorator, which we can use to validate options. The test function should take the function name, option name, and option value, and return `True` if the option value is valid and `False` otherwise.

Let us now define some function:

```
ClearAll[g];

Options[g]={"a"->1,"b"->False};

decorator[Function[{f, args, code}, 
  Print["The passed arguments were: ", args];code, 
  HoldAll]
] @
decorator[
  OptionCheck[optcheck]
] @ 
g[x_,y_,OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Module[{z=x+y,q,a},a=OptionValue["a"];
    q = If[OptionValue["b"],a,a+1];
    {x,y,q}
  ]
```

and we also need to define `optcheck`:

```
ClearAll[optcheck];
optcheck[g, "a",val_]:=IntegerQ[val];
optcheck[g, "b",val_]:=MatchQ[val,True|False];
```

Now we can test. First, testing the valid inputs:

```
g[1, 2]
g[1, 2, "a" -> 10]
g[1, 2, "a" -> 10, "b" -> False]
```

> During evaluation of In[392]:= The passed arguments were: {1,2}

```
(* {1, 2, 2} *)
```

> During evaluation of In[392]:= The passed arguments were: {1,2,a->10}

```
(* {1, 2, 11} *)
```

> During evaluation of In[392]:= The passed arguments were: {1,2,a->10,b->False}

```
(* {1, 2, 11} *)
```

where you can see that the outer decorator was printing the passed arguments.

Now, the input where some options are given values of inappropriate type:

```
g[1, 2, "a" -> 1.5]
```

> During evaluation of In[395]:= The passed arguments were: {1,2,a->1.5}
>
> During evaluation of In[395]:= OptionCheck::invldopt: Option a for function g received invalid value 1.5`

```
(* $Failed *)
```

and

```
g[1, 2, "a" -> 1, "b" -> 2]
```

> During evaluation of In[396]:= The passed arguments were: {1,2,a->1,b->2}
>
> During evaluation of In[396]:= OptionCheck::invldopt: Option b for function g received invalid value 2

```
(* $Failed *)
```

where you can see both decorators at play - the outer one was still printing the passed arguments, while the inner one detected invalid options, issued error message and returned `$Failed` without executing the body of the function.

### An aside: the role of decorators

In python, decorators are very useful. But not because you can modify the behavior of some existing function (because if the function already exists, chances are that you don't own it, but rather import it from some other package). The main usefulness of decorators is that they factor out the logic, which doesn't belong to the function you write, but rather should augment it in some way. For example, perform certain argument checks or checks of the result. Or even add some functionality to your function or class (for example, class decorators can add some methods to the class you define, and can be cheaper alternatives to metaclasses).

So, they are useful to add certain behavior and factorize some logic which can be implemented separately, from your main function. The main point is, you typically use decorators on the code *you* control / write, to have it more concise, and also when certain checks / etc have been already implemented elsewhere and you simply need to decorate your function to enable them.

Changing existing definitions is also a well-known practice in python, but it is called monkey-patching. This typically involves changes performed on existing functions or classes, where for example you can import a class and add or modify some of its methods at run-time. This is usually reserved to cases where you have to work around some bug or limitation in code which you use but don't own, and when other softer methods (such as subclassing) are not an option (for example, the authors of the package did not provide necessary hooks).

So in Mathematica too, changing definitions of already existing function generally doesn't strike me as a good idea. This is a much more intruding method, and the necessity of doing this means that you perform it on the code that you don't own / control. This can be much more error-prone, you can't easily chain this approach,  and I would consider this being the last resort, just like monkey - patching in python.

### Notes

The code presented above can surely be further improved and extended. I did not intend to provide a fully bulletproof production - quality implementation, this has rather a status of a proof - of - concept prototype. For example, conditional definitions such as `f[arg_]/;condition := rhs` won't work with the simple approach above, and there are a few other limitations. Perhaps, at some point the code above could become more robust, and then could actually be used for real applications.

Comment: How do you apply this to an already defined function?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You don't. At least, this is not how decorators are used in python.

Comment: Hm... Szabolcs wrote *I would like to do this without needing to know what f does, or how it behaves.* -- I interpreted this as meaning this kind of method was undesirable.  I guess he'll need to clarify that point, at least for me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The problem is, decorating an already existing function is a much tougher task. In python, decorators act at the function-definition time, where they have access to the function's definition. Also, in python, there is no function overloading, which simplifies things.

Comment: The original motivation came from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155564/12  The goal was to make sure that a certain context is in the context path while any function from the package is evaluated, but hopefully not have to add code manually to each and every public package function.

Comment: @Szabolcs From a cursory look, the method I have described should work in that case, similarly to what you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

A seemingly robust approach seems to be to modify the RHS of DownValues of the symbol you want to decorate. So lets define a decorator function:

```
decorate[f_Symbol] := (
 DownValues[f] = 
  Cases[DownValues[f], RuleDelayed[A_, expr_] :> RuleDelayed[A,
   Module[{result},
    Print["Before..."];
    result = expr;
    Print["After..."];
    result
   ]
  ]
 ]
)
```

This will modify all DownValue definitions of the symbol with the appropriate wrapper. (It will not work for built in symbols, and functions that are defined through other means e.g. UpValues)

We use the `Cases` statement for the replacement to ensure two things:

1. The RHS of the DownValues are not evaluated during decoration.
2. Only `DelayedRule` statements at the top level of the DownValues are replaced.

Example:

Lets define a function `f`:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_]:=x^2;
f[1] = 0; 
f[]  = Null;
```

We can then add the "decoration" by:

```
decorate@f;
```

evaluation of `f` then yields:

```
f[5]
During evaluation of In[]:= Before...

During evaluation of In[]:= After...
(* 25 *)
```

and

```
f[1]
During evaluation of In[]:= Before...

During evaluation of In[]:= After...
(* 0 *)
```

and

```
f[]
During evaluation of In[]:= Before...

During evaluation of In[]:= After...
(* Null *)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that argument-less case (`g[]`) is special and even if you manually reorder `DownValues` `HoldPattern[g[]]:>...` will stay on top.

Let's assume we don't have such definitions, quite often it will be enough:

```
g // ClearAll

g[sym_Symbol] := ToString[sym]

Module[{inside = False}
  ,
  PrependTo[
   DownValues[g],
   HoldPattern[g[sym___] /; TrueQ@Not@inside] :> Block[{inside = True}
     , Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myEmpty`"}, g[sym]]
     ]
   ]
  ];

Column @ DownValues[g]

g[sym]
```

> ```
> HoldPattern[g[sym$___]/;TrueQ[!inside$13949]]:>Block[{inside$13949=True}
>     , Block[
>           {$ContextPath={},$Context=myEmpty`}
>         , g[sym$]
>       ]
>   ]
> HoldPattern[ g[sym_Symbol] ] :> ToString[sym]
> ```

> ```
> "Global`sym"
> ```

It wouldn't work if we had a 'pure' V-G trick:

```
Module[{inside = False},
 g[sym___] /; TrueQ@Not@inside := Block[{inside = True}
   , Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myEmpty`"}, g[sym]]
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Literal DownValues (like g[1]) always come before pattern DownValues. The DownValues g[] is treated like a literal DownValues.

Comment: @CarlWoll makes sense, thanks. I wasn;t aware it will be respected when I `Set` `DownValues` manually too, other patterns are not sorted.